# Why are my website's background-image gifs using up all of my computer's CPU time?

Tags: css, html, gif, lag

I'm building a website ([www.experimonkey.com](http://www.experimonkey.com)) for which I use 3 .gif files (and a bootstrap carousel) on the homepage. One is behind a "login" link on the navigation bar and the others are the background for two columns. The two column .gifs use massive amounts of CPU time (all 4 cores of my laptop run close to 100%). I've optimized the files and tried converting them to .mp4 as suggested online--which actually seemed to be worse.

There must be something that I am doing incorrect, but I can't figure out the issue. As a side note, my website runs very smoothly on mobile, and the website from which I've taken the .gifs displays multiple on each of its pages with 0 lag. Below is my css. I realize it doesn't give much information, so please let me know if I can provide additional detail. Would it be better to use `<img>` here, and why?

```
.tile {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 4px outset black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #222222;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}

.tile:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #222222 inset;
}

#menu {
  padding-top: 63px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .tile-tall {
    height: 60vh;
  }
  #menu {
    padding-top: 73px;
  } 
}

.tile-link {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.tile-link:hover {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background-color 2000ms ease;
  background-color: #000000AA;
  color: black;
}

#tile-play {
  background-image: url("/img/dog_game.gif");
}

#tile-facts {
  background-image: url("/img/beaver_fact.gif");
}
```

Comment: For me it is all good in CPU.

Comment: @AjAX. which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181.

Comment: Hmm. Well, my Chrome was out of date, but I'm still having major lag issues. Any hunches why this would be, say, as compared to giphy.com, which is pretty much all gifs? I'm running a dual boot, and on Windows now, which is only 50% CPU (compared to Chromium and 100%), but giphy.com is still only about 15%.

Comment: How do you know the webs is causing that?

Comment: login.gif has no right being 500×500px but apart from that I think you just have to accept that GIFs and videos use quite a lot of processing power. Your website uses around 25% CPU for myself - I've seen worse. Giphy uses more like 30% for me. One thing they do, at least for Chrome, is serve up their animations on the homepage as WebP files. Maybe worth looking into but meh. What I'd recommend the most for yourself is using CSS animations to reduce bandwidth and keep it looking crisp at any resolution. Not sure if doing so will be better or worse for performance though.

Comment: I just realized also that there is significantly less lag when the window is set to the mobile layout on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help. I'll try looking into CSS animations and I guess keep messing around with it. It could just be my laptop in all honesty, but I would definitely like the page to be accessible.

Comment: FYI, No performance issue on my i7 920 and Chromium 64.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess here but if you want to reduce lag and CPU usage, maybe try setting the .mp4s to play only on element hover?

I've visited your website and I have no such problems with massive CPU usage - mine is around 6-8% percent on your website.

Also, if setting the mp4s to play only on element hover doesn't improve performance, maybe consider it as a design choice? All those animations playing at the same time can be distracting.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely a good suggestion and something that I'll look into. I had a few other effects I wanted to use, so using a background image was just the quickest way to prototype :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old; however, I had this same problem. I found that it was caused by having hardware acceleration turned off in the browser. Turning it on should resolve the problem.

Chrome:

`Settings > Advanced > System > Use hardware acceleration when available`

Edge:

`Settings > System and performance > Use hardware acceleration when available`